# Service in Docker throws UnknownHostException for bigquery table list

Tags: google-bigquery

Unit test execution and dockers in google kubernetes run just fine however when I run that docker in local, I started getting the following error from bigquery.

Any help is appreciated!

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: accounts.google.com
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.8.0_72-internal]
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
```

Comment: Is your local machine behind a firewall? The accounds.google.com address is used for authentication, and if you can't talk to that address you're not going to be able to make any Google API calls.

Comment: Like I said, on the same machine, I have been running the same docker for sometime and never got this error. On top of that, I am running unit tests in the java project, all is fine but not in docker...